# Matrix exponential in Python

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, python

Given the equation,

$$\begin{equation*}\exp(Ax)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}A^n\end{equation*}$$

implement in Python a function which calculates $\exp(Ax)$ for a given matrix $A$ and scalar $x$ using the equation directly. The only part that is troubleieng me is the equation. How can I implement an infinite sum in Python?

I'm allowed to test my result with the `expm` from `scipy.linalg` but I have to directly use the equation.

I have written the following code with help from previous answers.

```
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm

# Scalar x (will later on be for user input)
x = 1

matrix = np.array([[-5, 2, 3], [2, -6, 4], [4, 5, -9]])

# Using scipy to compute the matrix exponential (for comparison)
    
B = expm(matrix)
print(B)    

# Defining the equation
def equation(n):
    y = ((pow(x, n) * np.linalg.matrix_power(matrix, n)) / int(math.factorial(n)))
    return y


# Summing the equation with finite iterations
result = sum([equation(n) for n in range(0, 1000)])
print(result)
```

But it doesn't seem to give me the right answer. After hours of staring I can't seem to figure out the problem.

Comment: use $A=D+N$ decomposition, were $D$ diagonal (you can calculate $D^n$ easily) and $N$ nilpotent which renders the sum finite. Note: you can use Jordan form, it is a particular Dunford (or Jordan-Chevalley) D+N decomposition.

Comment: They probably want you to continue until the terms get small.  Continue until the maximum absolute value of an entry in the summand is less than some $\varepsilon$.  Make $\varepsilon$ an input to your function so that you can adjust it it your results don't compare well with the result of calling `expm`.

Comment: The trick is to stop the sum when the elements get sufficiently small.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for the quick response.

Comment: You would usually divide Ax by some power of 2 and use  exp(A) = exp( A / 2^k ) ^ (2^k).  The final power is efficiently computed by taking k times the square.  And yes, as others said,  A/2^k should be small enough so that the first 6 or 10 terms of the power series should suffice. (E.g. you should have  norm( A/2^k) ~ 0.01 or so, i.e.,  k ~ 6+ log_2 norm(A), but no need to compute a complicated norm, take e.g. the sup norm  max(abs(aij) for aij in A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepping through some calls to other functions, the crucial part of the source code is [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.2/scipy/sparse/linalg/matfuncs.py#L595-L682). @zwim provided a hint of how matrix exponentiation can be reduced to exponentiating scalars, but either way the basic answer, as @saulspatz noted, is that you can just add terms until new ones are so small they can be neglected.

For what it's worth, the not-so-basic answer (probably beyond the scope of what you need to implement in this exercise), which you'll see hinted at in the code I linked to, is to first check whether [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) are an adequate, more efficient alternative than partial sums of the exponential map. The algorithmic details get quite thorny beyond that point - in fact, I suspect some research into whether we can do something even better is still ongoing - but their motive is quite simple: the obvious choice of a computable iteration converging to a given limit [may not be the one that converges fastest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration).

Right, so how do we calculate $\exp(xA)$? One might exploit repeated squaring to get away with fewer terms, e.g.

```
def exp(A, x):
    Ax = A*x
    if max(np.absolute(Ax))>1e-4:
        sqrt = exp(A, x/2)
        return sqrt @ sqrt
    sq = Ax @ Ax
    return 1 + Ax + sq / 2 + sq @ Ax / 6
```

Note the above code doesn't explicitly check new terms are very small; it checks the matrix being exponentiated is very small. There's much about this code that has room for optimizations, but I leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed response. It made it all very clear! I'm not familiar with Python so it'll take some thinking before I'll fully understand your code. Nonetheless, thank you very much again.

Comment: Hi J.G.
I tried implementing your code, but I couldn't figure it out. I tried taking the approach that you sugested in your answer, but my code doesn't seem to work, even though i've taken your words into account. Would you be able to take a look at my code in the edited question, and possibly give me a hint as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Matt That you're calculating such high factorials looks like a recipe for disaster, but that's all I can discern without values or an error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a naive implementation:

```
def my_expm(A):
    m,n = np.shape(A)
    norm = np.sqrt(np.trace(A@A.H))
    k = 0
    fact = 1
    matpow = np.eye(n)
    expmat = np.matrix(np.zeros([n,n]))
    lastnorm = 1
    while lastnorm > 1e-8:
        expmat += matpow/fact
        lastnorm = np.max(abs(matpow/fact))
        k += 1
        fact *= k
        matpow = A@matpow
    return expmat

A = np.matrix('0, -1; 1 0')*np.pi
print(my_expm(A))
```

Comment: I've spent 5-6 hours trying to implement your and @J.G. 's code, but without any luck. Could you possibly look at the code I wrote in my edited question, and give me a hint as to why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Matt The entirety of the problem is rounding error. Your would be fine if the matrix were better behaved or if the computational precision were higher. If you divide the entries of the matrix by $10$ or equivalently take $x = 0.1$, you'll find that your code now gives an accurate answer

Comment: @Matt Some more points about your code: first of all, the thing that you define is not an "equation"; it's a function. Second, your code could be reduced to one line: `print(sum([np.linalg.matrix_power(matrix,k)/math.factorial(k) for k in range(0,100)]))`.

Comment: @Matt To elaborate on that first comment a bit: we run into trouble whenever the eigenvalues of $Ax$ are large in absolute value

Comment: Thank you very much, Ben. It finally works! As you may have noticed I'm very new to Python - thanks for the explanation and guidance.